# Mixed Effects modeling with multiple random effects in python

Tags: python, model, mixed

I have the following data set and I wanted to run a mixed effects linear model as below:

```
 Type    Season    Price     Sales
  A       Fall      34        500
  A       Winter    20        300
  B       Fall      15        100
  B       Winter    10        150

fm = model = smf.mixedlm("Sales ~ Price", df, groups = df[["Type","Season"]], 
                re_formula = "~Price")
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Could you please help me with this issue. This model can be easily done in R but I was not able to find a compatible example in python.

Comment: It looks like the issue is with your `re_formula`. From the documentation (emphasis mine): "random_effects – A _dictionary_ mapping the distinct group values to the conditional means of the random effects for the group given the data." Because it was expecting a dict, and dict keys must be hashable, you can't pass in a column or ndarray

Comment: It looks like there's a discussion on using this interface in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502398/python-statsmodels-mixedlm-mixed-linear-model-random-effects)

Comment: Do you mean that I need to pass random effects like this: {"Type": "1", "Season": 1}?

Comment: Unfortunately I've never used it myself, so I don;t know exactly how it needs to be entered, but you can try that and see if it prevents the error

Answer (score 0):

**You can use below vc_formula approach to solve the above problem .**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import random
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
data={'Type': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],'Season': ['Fall', 'Winter', 'Fall', 'Winter'],'Price': [34, 20, 15, 10],'Sales': [500, 300, 100, 150]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
fixed_formula='Sales ~ Price'
vc_formula={'g1': "0 + C(Type):C(Season)"}
oo=np.ones(df.shape[0])
model=sm.MixedLM.from_formula(fixed_formula, data=df, groups=oo,vc_formula=vc_formula)
results=model.fit()
print(results.summary())
random_effects_by_channel = results.random_effects
print(random_effects_by_channel)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).