# is this mixed effect from R convert it into python correct?

Tags: python, r, mixed-models, random-effects

I'm trying out a linear mixed effect from R and converted it into python, but both give different results. Do I convert it correctly? My R code:

```
lmer(A~B * C * D * E + (1 + B| F) , data=df,REML=FALSE)
```

`*` is the interaction between predictor. My python code:

```
smf.mixedlm('A ~ B * C * D * E', data=df,re_formula='B', group='F').fit(reml=False)
```

Comment: This question is somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502398/python-statsmodels-mixedlm-mixed-linear-model-random-effects?r